# Exporting CMake targets for an Autotools project

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, autotools

In many different places I found this guideline: "Upstreams should support downstream’s modern target-based design."

So I'm dealing with an Autotool based project, and I was able to build a reasonable `ProjectConfig.cmake.in` file that is parsed and used as a template by Autoconf.

```
get_filename_component(LibUsbgx_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${LibUsbgx_CMAKE_DIR})
list(REMOVE_AT CMAKE_MODULE_PATH -1)

set (prefix @prefix@)
set (exec_prefix @exec_prefix@)
set (libdir @libdir@)
set (includedir @includedir@)

set(LibUsbgx_INCLUDE_DIRS "@includedir@")

if(NOT TARGET LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx)
    add_library(LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_property(TARGET LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)

    set_target_properties(LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx PROPERTIES 
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "@libdir@/libusbgx.so"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "@includedir@")
endif()

unset (prefix)
unset (exec_prefix)
unset (libdir)
unset (includedir)

set(LibUsbgx_LIBRARIES LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx)
```

Two questions:

1. I had to use a tweak to make it work because `@libdir@` is expanded to `${prefix}/lib` and not in the full path; Is there a way to avoid this hack?
2. When crosscompiling it cannot work because `@prefix@` expands to `/usr` so the paths are absolute, but crosscompiling require them to be relative the system path. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not following why you are doing this.  The Autotools and CMake are separate tools for the same purpose.  They are *alternatives*, not usually considered complementary, so why are you trying to use Autoconf to create CMake input files?

Comment: Simply put, I'm using CMake and a library (LibUsbgx) that uses autotools. Providing the *Config.cmake file would help cmake users importing the library, as suggested in the quoted guideline, unless I misunderstood the guideline itself (possible).

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the file generated by cmake in another project, I improved the file this way:

```
# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
if(_IMPORT_PREFIX STREQUAL "/")
  set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "")
endif()
set(LibUsbgx_INCLUDE_DIRS "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include")

if(NOT TARGET LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx)
    add_library(LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_property(TARGET LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)

    set_target_properties(LibUsbgx::LibUsbgx PROPERTIES 
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libusbgx.so"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include")
endif()
```

I'm not sure it is the right way to do this with an `autotools` project, because libdir, includedir etc can be changed with `configure`ing the project.